# Return value of one field from Database[ Entity Framework ] [ ASP.NET MVC ]

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I'm working on a **ASP.NET MVC** project with **Entity Framework**, and **I want to return value of one field** from an database, and I won't to return full record, just value of one field.

This what I try :

```
    public JsonResult DUR_json(string FL)
    {
        var R = from F in DB_Context.Con.FLs where F.CODE_FL == FL select F.DUR_FL.First();


        return Json(new { DUR = R });
    }
```

But this code returns the full record, please any help ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `bracets`

**Like this :**

```
var R = (from F in DB_Context.Con.FLs where F.CODE_FL == FL select F.DUR_FL);
```

Wish this help.

**Note :** change the `from Entity` in the title to `from database`, this will help others to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Just select your field and then return first result:

```
var R = (from F in DB_Context.Con.FLs
         where F.CODE_FL == FL
         select F.DUR_FL).First();
```

Consider using `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()` if there might be no records with given `CODE_FL`

Comment: firstly thanks for your time, but bro I want just **One Field** exactly `DUR_FL`

Comment: `DUR_FL` is a navigation property according to your query `F.DUR_FL.First()` 
what type `DUR_FL` has?

Comment: didn't work bro, I got this error in the `View` : **DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.
Parameter name: input**

Comment: what type DUR_FL has?

Comment: `DUR_FL ` is a field in database

Comment: where i forgot the bracets